# Element wise calculation breaks autograd

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, logistic-regression

I am using pytorch to calculate loss for a logistic regression (I know pytorch can do this automatically but I have to make it myself). My function is defined below but the cast to torch.tensor breaks autograd and gives me w.grad = None. Im new to pytorch so Im sorry.

```
logistic_loss = lambda X,y,w: torch.tensor([torch.log(1 + torch.exp(-y[i] * torch.matmul(w, X[i,:]))) for i in range(X.shape[0])], requires_grad=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post isn't very clear on details and this is a monster of a one-liner. I first reworked it to make a [minimal, complete, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Please correct me if I misunderstood your intentions and please do it yourself next time.

```
import torch

# unroll the one-liner to have an easier time understanding what's going on
def logistic_loss(X, y, w):
    elementwise = []
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        mm = torch.matmul(w, X[i, :])
        exp = torch.exp(-y[i] * mm)
        elementwise.append(torch.log(1 + exp))

    return torch.tensor(elementwise, requires_grad=True)

# I assume that's the excepted dimensions of your input
X = torch.randn(5, 30, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.randn(5)
w = torch.randn(30)

# I assume you backpropagate from a reduced version
# of your sum, because you can't call .backward on multi-dimensional
# tensors
loss = logistic_loss(X, y, w).mean()
loss.mean().backward()
print(X.grad)
```

The simplest solution to your problem is to replace `torch.tensor(elementwise, requires_grad=True)` with [`torch.stack(elementwise)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.stack). You can think of `torch.tensor` as a constructor for entirely new tensors, if your tensor is more of a result of some mathematical expression, you should use operations like `torch.stack` or `torch.cat`.

That being said, this code is still wildly inefficient because you do manual looping over `i`. Instead, you could write simply

```
def logistic_loss_vectorized(X, y, w):
    mm = torch.matmul(X, w)
    exp = torch.exp(-y * mm)

    return torch.log(1 + exp)
```

which is mathematically equivalent, but will be *much* faster in practice, because it allows for better parallelization due to lack of explicit looping.

Note that there is still a numerical issue with this code - you're taking a logarithm of an exponential, but the intermediate result, called `exp`, is likely to attain very high values, causing loss of precision. There are workarounds for that, which is why the loss functions provided by PyTorch are preferable.